# How does this "index of char array with a char array" work?

Tags: r

I am reading [this article on fixing pie chart from WSJ](http://rud.is/b/2016/03/14/spinning-cycles-in-box-4-to-take-the-pies-out-of-pi-day/) using R's bar chart. There is complete code in the original article, so I won't repeat here. I am puzzled on this line:

```
dat$amount <- factor(amount_trans[dat$amount], levels=amount_trans)
```

In particular `amount_trans[dat$amount]`. I understand the overall goal is to replace original label with a "\n" for better formatting, and levels to fix the order. But I am not sure how this is done. `dat$amount` is a char array, `amount_trans` is also a char array. index of char array with a char array?

```
> dat$amount[1:2]
[1] "less_than_one_hour_per_week" "less_than_one_hour_per_week"



amount_trans <- c("less_than_one_hour_per_week"="<1 hr/\nwk", 
                  "one_to_four_hours_per_week"="1-4 hrs/\nwk", 
                  "one_to_three_hours_a_day"="1-3 hrs/\nday", 
                  "four_or_more_hours_a_day"="4+ hrs/\nday")
```

Above line does work as expected, this change the label as it intended.

However, the next use of it (similar idea and I still don't know why) just wouldn't work:

```
dat$Task <-factor(title_trans[dat$Task], levels=title_trans)
```

It returns some `NA` for whatever reason, here is what I tried:

```
> title_trans <- c("Basic exploratory data analysis"="Basic exploratory\ndata analysis", 
+                  "Data cleaning"="Data\ncleaning", 
+                  "Machine learning, statistics"="Machine learning,\nstatistics", 
+                  "Creating visualizations"="Creating\nvisualizations", 
+                  "Presenting analysis"="Presenting\nanalysis", 
+                  "Extract, transform, load"="Extract,\ntransform, load")
> head(dat$Task)
[1] "                  Basic exploratory data analysis" "                  Data cleaning"                   "                  Machine learning, statistics"   
[4] "                  Creating visualizations"         "                  Presenting analysis"             "                  Extract, transform, load"       
> dat$Task <-factor(title_trans[dat$Task], levels=title_trans)
> head(dat$Task)
[1] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
Levels: Basic exploratory\ndata analysis Data\ncleaning Machine learning,\nstatistics Creating\nvisualizations Presenting\nanalysis Extract,\ntransform, load
```

The `N/A` value is puzzling here. This also make the final plot not quite the same as demonstrated in screenshot.

Update: now I realized that the extra white space in the data cause the match gives out `NA`s. Puzzled resolved.

Comment: You do show a (more or less) reproducible example of what works, but not of what doesn't work. That makes answering your question hard. Anyway, have you studied `help("Extract")`?

Comment: you are right, I have amend the post to include the output that doesn't make sense to me: the `NA` after the `factor` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> index of char array with a char array?

No, index a *named character vector* (*not* array) with a vector of names:

```
values = c(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
values['a'] # 1
values[c('b', 'c')] # 2, 3
```

That’s all that’s happening there. I have no idea why the original author of the code put the vector names in quotes but it’s not necessary, and it’s in fact weird:

```
amount_trans <- c(less_than_one_hour_per_week = "<1 hr/\nwk", 
                  one_to_four_hours_per_week = "1-4 hrs/\nwk", 
                  one_to_three_hours_a_day = "1-3 hrs/\nday", 
                  four_or_more_hours_a_day = "4+ hrs/\nday")
```

Comment: The quotes around names are useful if the names are not valid syntax.

Comment: @Roland Use backticks in that case, not quotes. The fact that R allows quoted strings instead of identifiers is just conceptually lazy, and confusing for beginners.